# How do i set a function parameter with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

How do I set a function parameter with JavaScript?
I need to set a number value to a variable, but i cant seem to figure it out. some help will be much appreciated!

```
            // create web audio api context
        var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

        // create Oscillator node
        var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
        oscillator.type = 'square';
        oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(255, audioCtx.currentTime); // I want to set 255 to the variable x
        oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        oscillator.start();
        var x = document.getElementById("HTMLslider").value;
```

I have tried doing this:

```
set oscillator.frequency = var "x"
```

I hope someone can help

Comment: Your question is a little confusing...more clarity would help. How about like you did the others, `oscillator.frequency = "x"`. Or you could make your `createOscillator()` take input parameters which are assigned within the method itself.

Comment: It's not clear what you're after - you want to maybe use the value from your slider as the frequency value? (in this case currently statically set to 255?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to change the frequency according to the slider value:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("HTMLslider");

// create web audio api context
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

// create Oscillator node
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = 'square';
oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(Number(slider.value), audioCtx.currentTime); // I want to set 255 to the variable x
oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
oscillator.start();

// Listen for slider changes and apply value to frequency.
slider.addEventListener('change', e => oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(Number(e.target.value), audioCtx.currentTime));
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="225" id="HTMLslider" />
```

Comment: parseInt((slider.value)